# Prinfting multiple values in Assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64

So I do have some assembly code which I wrote on my linux VM (Manjaro, x86_64). It looks like this:

```
.section .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "The value of a is: %d, of b: %d"
    .text
    .globl main
    .type main, @function

main:

    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    subq $16, %rsp
    movl $15, -4(%rbp)
    movl $20, -8(%rbp)
    movl -8(%rbp), %edx
    movl -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl %eax, %esi
    movl $.LC0, %edi
    movl $0, %eax
    call printf
    movl $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

Basically I want to insert 2 values in registers, then somehow print them (formated like in `.LC0`). Well, I got stuck, so I just wrote C program, and used `gcc -S` to see how it looks. It gave me something similair to the code above. I don't understand two things:

1. If I store 20 in `%edx` and 15 in `%eax`, then why passing only `%eax` to `%esi` causes `printf` to print the values both from `%eax` and `%edx`?
2. Why do I have to put a zero constant everytime before and after `printf` (as `gcc` does?)

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the platform ABI. I believe you can find a link in the `assembly`-tag info.

Comment: As you add the tags C and gcc, please also show the equivalent C program you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I have to put a zero constant everytime before and after printf

These are two different issues.

Zero *before* `printf` conforms to [x86-64 a.k.a. AMD64 SysV ABI](http://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI) to specify count of variable arguments in vector (`XMMn`, `YMMn`...) registers.

Zero *after* `printf` is this function return value (likely, `return 0` at its end).

> why passing only %eax to %esi causes printf to print the values both from %eax and %edx?

It does not.

The same ABI specifies: the first argument (`printf` format string pointer) in `%rdi`; the second argument (first variable argument) in `%rsi`, and so on. Additional move of arguments seems to be artifact of non-optimized (`-O0`) `gcc` output code. If you add any optimization (even `-Og`), youʼll see these senseless moves wiped out.

Comment: So the next `printf` arguments are where?

Comment: @FrynioS see the link, the rules are listed there.

Comment: Under the AMD64 link?

Comment: Yes, exactly. BTW, ` movl $.LC0, %edi` seems wrong: you should use 64-bit instruction and register here (rdi), unless this VM is forced to use only 4GB.

Comment: This VM is forced to use exactly 4GB of RAM :D And I think thats why even gcc sometimes uses r- registers, and sometimes e- registers. Am I right?

Comment: Rxx means 64 bits. Exx means 32 bits. Also there are cases Exx used to reduce instruction length because 32-bit operation clears upper 32 bits of target Rxx; they are often used in gcc even if 64-bit operation is intended.